# Google Cloud: how do I give access to all projects billings in an organisation to CFO?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

It looks like there is a way to give access to a specific project, but not to entire organisation?

Comment: Grant permission at the project level.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to grant Billing Account Administrator role to the CFO. This role is an owner role for billing account and enables him to manage the billing accounts.
You can add your CFO as a member to the billing account and grant the Billing Account Administrator role. I would recommend checking this [link](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/billing-access) for more information.